# Overview of how to track mail move change notification ms graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our platform is replicating email functionality, I.e. view all emails folders and contents, reply, create new, draft, move etc for users.

We have successfully subscribed users to all change notifications (create, update, & delete) for the whole mailbox, however, we are not sure how to track folder move operations as I can’t find an example in the documentation and our current implementation is not working reliably.

The issue we have is that after receiving the various change notifications, when we are doing the requests to get the value for the updated/deleted message, sometimes the value returned is the updated value, not the original one, therefore if the folder has changed we do not know which message to delete. This issue is highlighted in the documentation here (half way down): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-change-notifications-overview?tabs=http#example-3-create-a-subscription-to-get-change-notifications-with-resource-data-for-a-message-based-on-a-condition-preview

We tried it using immutable ids, but the final webhook received was sometimes the delete webhook for the message ID. This is supposed to be for the original email that was moved, however because the message ID is the same (and the parent folder ID value is not reliable) we may end up deleting the wrong email.

With immutable turned off, we did not receive any delete notifications (only creates and updates), so we ended up with duplicate emails as the original was never deleted.

Is someone able to advise the correct procedure to track these events?

Thanks

Comment: If your using immutableid's and Single Item Recovery is switched on (which it is on by default) then you should only every see deletes of a Message when they are being purged from the dumpster (and that's going to be based on whatever retention policies are in place). Everything else is just a updated event so in theory anyway if the parent folderid isn't one of the recoverable items folder's than it could be a parent move.

Comment: Hi @GlenScales, thanks for your comment. I actually made a separate ticket about this behaviour here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75116988/inconsistent-change-notifications-for-ms-graph-api as you can see, I get deleted notifications even when messages are moved folders, although the behaviour is inconsistent

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is Exchange is an object store so when you do a delete in the client or even a move it just updates the object. The parent folder of a Message for example is just an Id property so moving an item between a folder doesn't delete and recreate the object it just updates one property on the object. How the dev's translate that through in the Graph can become a bit muddled but if you understand the underlying way it works that may help. Different clients eg Outlook, Outlook Mobile, OWA use different client protocol's so there are some challenges there as well.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the only reliable way to do this is using the delta query - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages - whenever a change notification is received for a folder.

So, when authorisation is provided for access to a users mailbox, you must get subscriptions for each folder and then whenever a change notification is received for that folder/subscription, the delta query is run for that folder.

I believe that MS are in beta testing for providing the change information in the webhook which in my option would be a great improvement in efficiency in terms of implementation and operation.

Hope this helps someone in the future!